# Interactive dashboard in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, charts

I would like to create a dashboard in ASP.NET with multiple reports (bar, sparkline, table) and when user select any particular area in the graph other graph should get filter by that selection.
Just like how Qlikview works, example [here](http://us.demo.qlik.com/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvdocs/Call%20Detail%20Record%20Analysis.qvw&host=Demo11&anonymous=true)

How to create similar kind of dashboard in ASP.NET, without using any third party (paid) tool?

Is there any framework or plugin available to implement this kind of functionality?

Is it possible to create such kind of functionality via standard ASP.NET Chart controls?

Comment: Yes. Lots of work, but yes.

Comment: @Alexander Is there any framework or plugin available to implement this kind of functionality?

Comment: @Alexander Can you assist me by providing an idea/approach for implementing it via generic ASP.NET chart control? I personally feel quite comfortable with ASP.NET controls

Comment: The amount of work exceeds this community, sorry.

Comment: @Alexander I am sorry if I meant that but I am not looking for actual code. I was just seeking an approach/framework to get the same. Anyways, you gave me a hope that this is possible :) I will see if I can get it with via ASp.NET controls itself. Thanks anyways.

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557077/drag-and-drop-files-in-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the rich UI you showed, eigther you can code them using javascript from scratch or use opensource or paid third party components.

Any ASP.NET control renderes to standard HTML and Javascript only, so no point taking one more additional load from the "server side" controls.

There are plenty of free charting libraries which you can use to create most of the screen. please have a look.

http://www.splashnology.com/article/15-awesome-free-javascript-charts/325/

Also, Kendo UI (unfortunately its not free), is a robust framework (Javascript/MVC), which do have tons of builtin components and features to get a view like that or beyond.

or, you can use these feature rich HTML5 admin templates, and manipulate the UI via javascript/Jquery.

http://themeforest.net/item/simplicity-massive-admin-pack/full_screen_preview/6862788

Complete list of templates can be found at.

http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-templates

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend using free data visualization libraries implemented with JavaScript.

We used [ChartJs](http://www.chartjs.org), [Sparkline](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/) and [D3](http://d3js.org/). They will help you implementing visualizations. If you also need to list data you can use free table and grid libraries.

Unfortunately it is not free but for drag-drop functionality you can use [JDash MVC](http://mvc.jdash.net) or [WebForms](http://aspnet.jdash.net).