# Drag and drop the entire canvas and show a new area of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, seadragon

Has anyone tryed to move a entire canvas using a drag and drop method ?

I mean something like [open sea dragon](http://openseadragon.codeplex.com/)

I am developing a online game and my buildings do not fit within a 1000 x 700 pixel screen, so i need a canvas;

The canvas should be somehow created within another area, and the entire canvas should be draggable, so that the entire village becomes available;

I need to use a matrix of 3 x 3 screens, thats 9 screens in full hd, in order to store and render the entire village ground and buildings, this is why i need the canvas draggable;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557077/drag-and-drop-files-in-mvc

Comment: this is not a upload by drag and drop issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like http://www.pixijs.com/. You could also use OpenSeadragon's viewport component but do the drawing yourself; that's what I do in http://driftory.com.